# Bootstrap Cards: Place Subtitles in the Upper Right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does Bootstrap Card have any built in functionality to place Subtitles in the Upper right like this? Otherwise, I will not use the Bootstrap card option, just use a regular css flex container.

**Ideal Goal:**

[image]

**Existing Bootstrap Functionality:**

I see Bootstrap only allows this option where Subtitle is directly below the Title.

[image]

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any such property directly in bootstrap. But this can be done by overriding some css of bootstrap.

You can use `d-inline-block` style of boostrap to make title and subtitle come in the same line and then change the subtitle to float in right.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="d-inline-block card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="d-inline-block card-subtitle text-muted float-right margin-top" style="margin-top:.2rem;">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! subtitle seems little higher, how can straighten it out a bit?

Comment: Please Check now.

Comment: thanks, can you also code review my answer? Seems like I have too many classes, but I wanted to inherit bootstrap property and flex container property in one, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```css
.card-subtitle.text-muted {

position: absolute;
right: 1.25em;
margin: 0;
top:2.25em;
background:blue;
color:white !important;
padding:2px;
border-radius:5px;
font-size:10px;
   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try just modifying the bootstrap style with your own modifications:

```
.card-subtitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25em;
    right: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You might want to use that other class in the selectors also:

```
.card-subtitle.text-muted {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
    top:2.25em;
    background:blue;
    color:white !important;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:10px;

}
```

Comment: subtitle seems little high, anyway to straighten it out? thanks !

Comment: I see two css classes by the way

Comment: You can play around with top and padding:  `.card-subtitle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:1.75em;
   }

Answer (score 1):

Utilize Flex Container and Space Between

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card{
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="flex-container card-title"><div>Card title</div> <div>Card Subtitle </div></h5>

    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```